# PHP - getting inner HTML code of two elements

Tags: php, innerhtml

I am currently in a transition process, I want to make CMS of my existing website. Until now (for a few years) I was generating and saving complete html files, and I want to store content of those pages in a database. My luck, I think, is that two elements I want to take from each html are unique inside one html file and same in all files. I have tried this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $string= file_get_contents($entry);
            $pattern = "/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/";
            preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $uname);
            $pattern = '/<p class=\"user_info\"><strong>(.*?)<\/strong><\/p>/';
            preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $udesc);
            echo "NAME: ".$uname[1][0]."<br>";
            echo "DESC: ".$udesc[1][0]."<br>";
            //MYSQL SAVING WILL GO HERE
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Above code extracts (h1)NAME(/h1) (imagine that (==< and )==>) part, but not (p class="user_info")(strong)CONTENT(/strong)(/p) part, it is just blank.

I have also tried different method:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $string= file_get_contents($entry);
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTML($string);
            $h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0)->textContent;
            echo "NAME: ".$h1."<br>";
            $p = $doc->saveHtml($doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)); // $p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->textContent; loads content, just without html tags, so I can not use it... :S
            echo "DESC: ".$p."<br>";
            //MYSQL SAVING WILL GO HERE
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Above code works, but not as expected. I need complete HTML code of paragraph, not just text. I have also tried $doc->savehtml(), still nothing.

Please help, and thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `$doc->saveHtml($doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));` (without `->textContent`)?

Comment: @metadings: yes, tried it again now just to be sure. No luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove `->textContent`

```
$h1 = $doc->saveHtml($doc->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0));
echo "NAME: ".$h1."<br>";
$p = $doc->saveHtml($doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));
```